# salesforce get token using jQuery ajax method

Tags: ajax, accesstoken

I have just intigrated the salseforce api using curl in php and its working fine but now i have to using the same thing with ajax so no curl is used here below is my code

```
var param = {
grant_type: "password",
client_id : "CLIENT_ID",
client_secret : "CLIENT_SECRET",
username:"USERNAME",
password:"PASSWORD"};
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token',
        type: 'POST',
        data: param,
        dataType: "json",
        crossDomain: true,
        contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        success: function (response) {
            console.log('Successfully retrieved ' + response);
            alert(JSON.stringify(response));
        },
        error: function (response) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(response));
        }

    });
```

when i alert the response than showing below response

[image]

and when inspect the response then showing that i am getting the access token and instance url same as when i am using in the CURL but its not alert the data or not showin in the console log just controll move in the error part of code and alert the error data as above image so what i am doing wrong

Please help me what's wrong and how to solve this problem

Thanks

Comment: Please do not post access tokens for your org. That token would allow anyone to access your org and your data or your client's data. Please post the JSON response and _redact secret values_.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion can you tell me problem in my code whan i am doing wrong i am using same code as shoing on this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25021482/salesforce-oauth-with-rest-api-using-javascript

Comment: How did you fix the issue?